# Why is Microsoft redirecting me to alternate language versions of their Update Catalog?

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-edge, microsoft

I was browsing an article on the Microsoft website when a link redirected me to a Chinese language version of the Microsoft Update Catalog. There was no token in the URL, so I don't know why this was happening.

I was browsing [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/sha-2-code-signing-support-update-for-windows-server-2008-r2-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-september-23-2019-84a8aad5-d8d9-2d5c-6d78-34f9aa5f8339), and under "Method 2: Microsoft Update Catalog", clicked on the link for [Microsoft Update Catalog](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/search.aspx?q=kb4474419) which is a clean URL to `http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/search.aspx?q=kb4474419`. This redirected me to the correct KB update, but in Chinese.

[image]

I tried clicking on the homepage link on the top left, re-entered the KB number on search, but the listing was still in Chinese. Interestingly, entering just "Windows" in the search box showed English results.

Out of curiosity, I Googled the KB number and the first link was identical, other than displaying as https:

`https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/search.aspx?q=kb4474419`

But being redirected from Google showed English results:

[image]

I'm not sure what I did wrong or why I am seeing results in Chinese.

Actually... I tried clicking on the link from the Microsoft website again and now it's in French??

[image]

What's going on?

I am using Microsoft Edge and Windows 10. There is nothing special about my environment that I can think of which would cause this to occur.

Comment: 2. If you look at the cookies for that page((View, edit, and delete cookies)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/storage/cookies]), does anything stand out, such as the `display-culture` cookie being set wrong? While you're doing that, you might want to delete the cookies and start again to see if corrects itself.

Comment: 1. Are you using a VPN?

Comment: The two URLs are not identical. When I click on the link, on iOS, it was in Spanish. “ v7/site/” does something, but as questions about websites are out of scope, it’s not a cookie. I browsed the same website in Private sessions and the behavior chnaged

Comment: There could also be third-party cookies causing that, if you have a browser that allows cross-site cookies. See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/third-party-cookies-firefox-tracking-protection, for example.

Comment: Try another browser than Edge. Try also to clear Edge cookies and cache.

Comment: I'm not using a VPN. The problem seems to have solved itself. I haven't even restarted my browser.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem went away on its own.